# html5 canvas, how to export a 2x image?

Tags: image, html, canvas, export, hdpi

I designed a web app with html5 canvas. To export an image, the code will be below:

```
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Is there any way to export a 2x image?

It is for hdpi display like apple retina display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are a few ways but every time you stretch a non vector image you will get some pixel distortion. However if its only two times the size you could get away with it using nearest neighbor. The below example shows two different methods, one is just stretching the image, the other uses nearest neighbor with a zoom factor of two.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/XTaxD/)**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2"),
    ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d"),
    tempCtx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d'),
    img = document.getElementById("testimg"),
    zoom = 2;

tempCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
var imgData = tempCtx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height).data;

canvas.width = img.width * zoom;
canvas.height = img.height * zoom;;

// nearest neighbor
for (var x = 0; x < img.width; ++x) {
    for (var y = 0; y < img.height; ++y) {
        var i = (y * img.width + x) * 4;
        var r = imgData[i];
        var g = imgData[i + 1];
        var b = imgData[i + 2];
        var a = imgData[i + 3];
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + "," + (a / 255) + ")";
        ctx.fillRect(x * zoom, y * zoom, zoom, zoom);
    }
}

// stretched
ctx2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 140, 140);
```

@phrogz has a great example of this [here](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_image_zoom.html) as well, showing a few different ways you can accomplish image re-sizing.

Comment: Yep!  You could even use splining to reduce the pixilation.  In particular I've used B-Splining to take an intricate image and make it look acceptable at 4X. I guess it's all a tradeoff between effort required and image distortion accepted!